# How to modify javascript to have html result instead of show out the html code in a comment system?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently,
when i input `<a href="#">test</a>`,
the comment system directly show my typing, "`<a href="#">test</a>`"

[image: current screen]

Modify to,
I would like the modify the javascript code that when i input `<a href="#">test</a>`,
it convert to html result "test" (a hyperlink to "#").

[image: Modify to]

How can i modify following code? Many thanks!

```js
function fetchComments(leaveRequestId) {

  $('#existingComments').html(lang_Loading);
  params = 'leaveRequestId=' + leaveRequestId;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: getCommentsUrl,
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      var count = data.length;
      var html = '';
      var rows = 0;

      $('#existingComments').html('');
      if (count > 0) {
        html = "<table class='table'><tr><th>" + lang_Date + "</th><th>" + lang_Time + "</th><th>" + lang_Author + "</th><th>" + lang_Comment + "</th></tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          var css = "odd";
          rows++;
          if (rows % 2) {
            css = "even";
          }
          var comment = $('<div/>').text(data[i]['comments']).html();
          html = html + '<tr class="' + css + '"><td>' + data[i]['date'] + '</td><td>' + data[i]['time'] + '</td><td>' +
            data[i]['author'] + '</td><td>' + comment + '</td></tr>';
        }
        html = html + '</table>';
      } else {

      }
      $('#existingComments').append(html);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="existingComments">
  <span><?php echo __('Loading') . '...';?></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var comment = $('<div/>').text(data[i]['comments']).html();
> ```

You're explicitly escaping the data from the Ajax request so that it shows up as text and isn't treated as HTML source code.

If you don't want to do that, then just don't do it!

(Do be careful not to expose yourself to [stored XSS attacks](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/cross-site-scripting-xss-attacks/) though)

Comment: I modify text to html, then it works! Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

$('#existingComments').html(html);

Comment: That won't change the content they are inserting. It just means it will replace whatever is there already instead of being added to it.

Comment: (1) Please stick to English on this site (2) Answers should address the question; it's fine to point out other problems, as an aside if you are answering the question (which you aren't). (3) The question already has `$('#existingComments').html(''); so it doesn't have the problem you imagine it does.